# Drupal 8, Browser language detection fails after some time (anonymous users)

Tags: caching, drupal-8

We are using Drupal 8 in the latest version (currently 8.6.1). We are having 5 different languages and we are automatically showing the language of the user's browser (also for anonymous users). After clearing cache, that works well for some time. At some point (a few hours), it stops working for only anonymous users and only shows one language, regardless of the browser language. Authenticated users don't have the issue.

I know it is not possible for you to tell me what the issue is. But can you please help me how I can nail down the root cause. I have tons of modules installed, so deactivating each individually and test (waiting for a few hours) is pretty painful.

One note, we have about 2000 visitors per hour.

First, we thought it is related to our CDN. But we added a second domain which directly accesses the web server and on this domain it is happening as well.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the issue. It is already described here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2986325

> Browser language detection is skipped, if a browser/robot without Accept-Language header calls the page and the default language node is put into cache. Afterwards, the default language node is always delivered until cache is cleared/rebuilt, the browser language of subsequent requests is ignored.

A patch is provided.